# Find the nearest set of coordinates in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, coordinates, worksheet-function

There are two tables, each with a coordinate pair: longitude and latitude, in decimal degrees (i.e. 37.23222, -121,3433). How do I match table A with its nearest coordinate pair in table B?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try filling down this formula from `G1` as shown below:

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,MMULT((B$1:C$10-E1:F1)^2,{1;1})),A$1:A$10)
```

For a more accurate formula that takes account of the circular distances try filling down from `H1`:

`=LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,SIN((RADIANS(B$1:B$10-E1))/2)^2+SIN((RADIANS(C$1:C$10-F1))/2)^2*COS(RADIANS(B$1:B$10))*COS(RADIANS(E1))),A$1:A$10)`

[image]

Comment: The first formula was accurate. I compared the results by mapping and spatial-joining the data. the 1st formula results were 100% match with the mapped results.

Comment: The first formula is only accurate if you treat longitude and latitude as a unit x and unit y change. For locations on the surface of the earth this will only be a reasonable approximation near the tropics. The second formula is based on a standard formula for spherical distances: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Answer (score 3):

This problem was solved back in 2006 by Tom Ogilvy [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/537429-closest-neighbour-coordinates.html), also found [here](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/closest-neighbour-coordinates.2523576/).

**The sample that I created:**

[image]

**Original problem:**

> I have 20 named locations in a coordinates. Every point have x,y.
>
> column a has the location name
>   column b has the x cooedinate
>   column c has the y coordinate
>
> Now i have 400 coordinates in 2 columns (column e and f ) and want to
>   have the name of the closest location (of the 20 named in column a) in column g.

**Original solution by Tom Ogilvy:**

> Assuming original data starts in A1, B1 and C1 with first locations in E1
>   and F1
>
> If you don't want to fill your sheet with formulas, you can put this in G1
>   committed/entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter rather than just enter since it is
>   an array formula, then drag fill it down the 400 rows.
>
> =INDEX($A$1:$A$20,MATCH(MIN(SQRT(($B$1:$B$20-E1)^2+($C$1:$C$20-F1)^2)),SQRT(
>   ($B$1:$B$20-E1)^2+($C$1:$C$20-F1)^2),0),1)