# Finding nearest coordinates on excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, coordinates, latitude-longitude, geocode

I have Latitude and longitudes for UPS stores. Column a has UPS store code, Column b is the latitudes, Column c  is the longitude. I also have another list of latitude (column e) and longitudes  (column f) for random Walmart locations. I need to find the nearest set of coordinates of the Walmart and ups stores for shortest driving distance

```
=INDEX($A$3:$A$434, MATCH(MIN(SQRT((E11-B$3:B$434)^2+(F11-C$3:C$434)^2)), SQRT((E11-B$3:B$434)^2+(F11-C$3:C$434)^2), 0))
```

I tried this formula (very popular when I search for the solution-however, it works on my small sample data (rows of 10)- However when I try it on the data I need (400+ rows), every single cell returns #VALUE!

Attached is example of my sample data its working on
[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Your formula will not provide driving distance.

Comment: Like Ron Rosenfeld commented: nearest location is not necessarily shortest driving distance, but most definately isn't equal to the distance.

Comment: I just tried your formula on 600 rows, and it worked perfectly. Without knowing your data we can't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look here: [Find the nearest set of coordinates in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384055/find-the-nearest-set-of-coordinates-in-excel?noredirect=1&lq=1)