# Excel Index Match with multiple Criteria and approximate match

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, approximate

I have an excel sheet with Criteria A, Criteria B, and Output C with about 332,000 rows of data. I have a list of input A & Input B on a separate sheet. I am trying to find output C with an approximate match of criteria A and B. I have the below formula that works well with a sample data of 21 rows but no matter what I do, it is not working with my full dataset. What am I doing wrong?

| Column H | Column I | Column J |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 35.12345 | -82.456123 | IOO45678 |
| 34.56789 | -83.12398 | IA001234 |

If my input data is in cell V3 (corresponding to Column H), and cell W3 (corresponding to column I), my formula goes as such:

```
=INDEX(
    J2:J332000, 
    MATCH(MIN(ABS(H2:H332000-V3) & MIN(ABS(I2:I332000-W3), 
    ABS(H2:H332000-V3) & ABS(I2:I332000-W3), 
    0
    )
)
```

I am getting a #N/A error. I have double checked the data, the formula but I am not seeing any mistakes. Also I tried this same formula and it works in a sample dataset of 20 rows with the same data. I am expecting an approximate match from the first two columns and data returned from the third column

Comment: Try adding something between the concatenation: `=INDEX(
    J2:J332000, 
    MATCH(MIN(ABS(H2:H332000-V3) & "|" & MIN(ABS(I2:I332000-W3), 
    ABS(H2:H332000-V3) & "|" & ABS(I2:I332000-W3), 
    0
    )
)
`

Comment: IF that does not work then you are probably having issues with scalability.  These are array formula and that could cause issues with such a large database.  Or you never have a time where the min for both functions are on the same line.  You could have a different min row in column H than a min row in Column I. For example using your data, if V3 had 34 and W3 had -82, It would not return a match because the two formula would return results on different rows.

Comment: I think these approaches would work better for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384055/find-the-nearest-set-of-coordinates-in-excel

Comment: @ScottCraner Hey how did you know I was working on lat/long data lol? That solution worked perfectly!!! Thanks so much

Comment: I work in the assessment industry and we use lat lng a lot.  In fact I just had to teach a user what those numbers mean just this morning.